# Nuxt redirect double back issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am having an issue with nuxt redirects, after going to an external redirect and press back, you go back along to route twice. I am handing redirects through the nuxt middleware, is there a way to get the router to update the history or better way to handle redirects in vue/nuxt?

This is the middleware redirect code:

```
export default function ({ route, redirect }) {
    // find the redirect if it exists where the from === the requested url
    var r = redirects.find(r => r.from === route.fullPath)
    //If it exists, redirect the page with a 301 response else carry on
    if (r) {
        // console.log("Redirecting: {from: " + r.from + ", to: " + r.to + "}")
        return redirect(r.to)
    }
}
```

redirects.json

```
[
    {
        "from": "/google",
        "to": "https://www.google.com"
    }
]
```

Here is a live version: https://admiring-benz-140867.netlify.app/
and code: https://github.com/aholland909/nuxt-test-project